# Spock: How to clear checkbox if already checked

Tags: checkbox, groovy, spock, geb, navigator

How to uncheck a checkbox using Navigator object?
I have

```
def checkboxes = $("input",class:"targetMltChk", name:"facility")
```

which is a group of checkboxes and some of them are checked. I want to uncheck all of them.

UPDATE:
I tried the below:

```
checkboxes.each{
                println it = false
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
checkboxes*.value(false)
```

I believe that should uncheck them all...

Comment: Thank you very very very much for the excellent solution. Grateful to you. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them works as well:

```
checkboxes*{
    it.value(false)
}

checkboxes.each{
    it.value(false)
}
```